# Having trouble with Javascript autocomplete library when getting data with getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery-events, jquery-ui-autocomplete, race-condition, getjson

I'm running into issues with the following code:

```
var setupSearch = {

searchSuggest: function(field) {
    $.getJSON('/get-all-journals', {'url':'on'}, function(data) {

        var SHCount = Number($.cookie('SHCount'));
        var SHArray = new Array();
        for (i=1; i <= SHCount; i++) {
            SHArray.push($.cookie('SH'+i));
        }
        $(field).ddautocomplete(removeDuplicate(SHArray), data.response.docs, {
            matchContains: true,
            max: 5,
            cacheLength: 5000,
            selectFirst: false,
            scroll: false,
            formatResult: function(str) { return str; },
            formatItem2: function(item) {
                return item.journal_display_name;
            },  
            formatMatch2: function(item) {
                return item.journal_display_name;
            },  
            formatResult2: function(item) {
                return item.journal_display_name;
            }   
        }); 
    }); 
},  
                
                        
searchForm: function(form) {

    var field = form.find('textarea');
    // Setup query field for default text behavior
    // setupField(field);

    setupSearch.searchSuggest(field);
    field.autogrow();
        
    field.keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            form.submit();
            return false;
        }   
    }); 

    // Make all forms submitting through Advanced Search Form
    form.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setupSearch.submitSearch(form, field);
    });
}, 


 submitSearch: function(form, field) {
    if (advancedSearch.checkMinFields() || (!field.hasClass('defaultText') && field.val() != '')) {
        // Sync the refine lists
        // syncCheckboxLists($('#refineList input'), $('#advancedRefineList input'));
        form.find('button').addClass('active');
        $('#advancedSearchForm').submit();
    } else {
        $('#queryField').focus();
    }
},
```

When I try to use the autocomplete drop-down by hitting enter, it seems to hit a "race condition" where the form will submit what I've typed rather than what autocomplete places into the textfield. Is there some way I can control the order of events so that the `form.submit()` will use what autocomplete fills into the text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual autocomplete dropdown menu is most likely represented as a styled list (or some other element) that is floated to be positioned below the textbox. On submit, have your function wait (a second or two max) for the autocomplete menu to be either destroyed or hidden. This will ensure that the plugin has time to fill in the textbox before the data is submitted.

**EDIT**

Try something like this:

```
$("#myDropdown").bind("autocompleteclose", function(){
    // Continue with submitting your form
});
```

Use that where you would submit your form, and put the submitting code inside the callback. That way, it will wait for the autocomplete to close before submitting the form. You will want to add some kind of timeout to this to prevent it from submitting after a long delay (not sure when something like this might happen, though).

Comment: I'm using the jQuery autocomplete plugin but with modifications to allow 2 datasets. Which function do you recommend waiting? The form submit function? And would I do this using setTimeout?

Comment: There are dozens. Is it the jQuery UI built-in one (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)?

Comment: Ok. I'll try it. What will trigger the "autocompleteclose" event tho? Do I need to add a trigger to the autocomplete plugin when I hit enter?

Comment: No, jQuery UI will trigger it automatically when the menu closes.

Comment: Thanks it works! However, it introduced a new issue where if the user tries to submit the form with enter before the autocomplete loads, then they cannot submit the form.

Comment: Is the problem that pressing Enter tries to autocomplete and submit the form at the same time?

Comment: No, it wasn't submitting the form at all if I didn't choose from the autocomplete dropdown. So I added the form.submit() code that I already had below the bound form.submit() code that you recommended and it works. For some reason the "race condition" is removed as well. Now it submits the field if nothing from autocomplete was chosen or if i chose something from autocomplete. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: You are welcome! Be sure to do some more race-condition testing, since I could have very well introduced another one that you haven't discovered yet. Good luck!